# Оптимизация кода на python

Tags: python

У меня была задача:

> Арнольд Шварценеггер стреляет в ужасного монстра Годзиллу из дробовика. Нужно найти общую величину урона, нанесённого Годзилле выстрелом.
>
> Подсказка: возможно, для быстрой работы программы вам пригодится алгоритм Евклида.
>
> Формат ввода
>
> Сначала вводится количество дробинок.
> Затем урон от каждой дробинки. Урон от каждой дробинки выражается простой дробью, её числитель и знаменатель вводятся на отдельных строках.
>
> Формат вывода
>
> Суммарный урон, выраженный простой несократимой дробью с дробной чертой между числителем и знаменателем.
>
> Пример
>
> Ввод
>
> ```
> 3
> 1
> 60
> 1
> 30
> 1
> 100
> ```
>
> Вывод
>
> ```
> 3/50
> ```

Я написал следующий код:

```
n = int(input())  a = list()  b = list()  c = list()  for plkj in range(n):
a.append(int(input()))
b.append(int(input())) tmp = 1 lol = [] for g in b:
tmp *= g for i in range(1, tmp + 1):
tmpl = 0
for j in b:
    if i % j == 0:
        tmpl += 1
if tmpl == len(b):
    lol.append(i) for ghj in range(len(b)):
c.append(a[ghj] * (lol[0] // b[ghj])) c1 = sum(c) b1 = lol[0] while c1 != 0 and b1 != 0:
if c1 > b1:
    c1 %= b1
else:
    b1 %= c1 print(str(sum(c) // (c1 + b1)) + '/' + str(lol[0] // (c1 + b1)))
```

Но это решение не прошло по времени, а как оптимизировать не понимаю, буду рад помощи

Comment: Наведите порядок в отступах, показанный сейчас код вообще не способен запуститься

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Считаем **общий знаменатель** перемножением всех знаменателей: `60*30*100 = 180000`
2. Считаем **общий числитель** как сумму всех числителей, перемноженных на все  остальные знаменатели (кроме того, который под текущим числителем): `1*30*100+1*60*100+1*30*60 = 10800`
3. Находим НОД **общего числителя** и **общего знаменателя** [алгоритмом Евклида](https://younglinux.info/algorithm/euclidean), он равен `3600`
4. Делим **общий числитель** и **общий знаменатель** на НОД.

```
# эмуляция ввода данных
inp = """3
1
60
1
30
1
100""".split('\n')


def input(): return inp.pop(0)
# конец эмуляции ввода данных

shots = [(int(input()), int(input())) for _ in range(int(input()))]
summ_uron = 1
for n, u in shots:
    summ_uron *= u
summ_shots = 0
for n, u in shots:
    summ_shots += n * summ_uron // u

a, b = summ_uron, summ_shots

while a != 0 and b != 0:  # Алгоритм нахождения НОД делением (Алгоритм Евклида)
    if a > b:
        a = a % b
    else:
        b = b % a

nod = a + b
print(f'{summ_shots // nod}/{summ_uron // nod}')
```

```
3/50
```